# React Native Flatlit - Keyextractor from an array

Tags: react-native

I would like to use the keyextractor for a Flatlist using the ISBN code that Google Books gives back:

```
"industryIdentifiers": [{ "identifier": "8870755312", "type": "ISBN_10" }, { "identifier": "9788870755312", "type": "ISBN_13" }],
```

I tried something like this but doesn't work

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier}
```

any idea? Thanks

Comment: (item, index) => item.industryIdentifiers[index].identifier if you have the same index as the data array

Comment: thanks. I don't think so, cause it always gives `undefined is not an object`

Comment: Does all items have an array of industryIdentifiers as a property ?

Comment: not sure but I think so, cause is google books API

Comment: but wait maybe not all

Comment: That maybe the issue, i tried with setting some and go the error

Comment: true. I didn't think about it but the ISBN is from the 80s on, maybe cause of that

Comment: Yes then you should chose something else :)